# pth Norm of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was going through a machine learning course. I learned about $L_1$ and $L_2$ norm of vectors in many operations. I read about that. According to the definition of the norm of vector, it is "The $p$th norm of a vector measures the "size" or magnitude of the vector $x$ in $p$-dimensional space ". How we can visualise the vector of d-dimension is measured in p-dimensional space. What is geometrical intuition formula we can easily calculate. But what is the intuition behind them. If my vector $x= [1,1,1]^\top$, its $3$rd norm is cube root of 3. But what is this distance? In $1$st norm it will be distance, for $2$nd norm displacement (intuitively) but for $3$rd norm what will it be?